# Where can I ask questions about moving a grand piano?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I am soon moving my belongings including a grand piano a few hundred miles, and I was wondering if there is a Stack Exchange site where I can ask moving questions (mainly about moving the piano). Looking through both the list of current sites and the Area 51 proposals, I didn't see a lot of promising candidates. The closest fits that I found were:

**Travel**: I suppose I will be traveling with my belongings, but moving is not mentioned in [the list of acceptable question topics](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for the site.

**Music Practice & Theory**: The main focus of the site (as the name suggests) is on playing music and music theory, though [the list of acceptable question topics](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) includes "instrument maintenance," which seems potentially related.

Is there any Stack Exchange site (one of these two or others) where I could ask questions about moving a piano? Is there a site where I could ask more generally about moving?

Comment: One of the "inventors" of mountain biking is/was a piano mover:  http://sonic.net/~ckelly/Seekay/kelly_moving.htm

Comment: Probably nowhere.  But your local professional long distance mover should have the tools and knowledge to break it down, pack it up and haul it for you.  Estimates are free.  You'll definitely have to get it tuned on the other end, if you care about that.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Kinda depends on your question... The devil is in the details:

- The logistics of your route, hiring a mover, bribing border officials, might be appropriate for Travel
- The care of and cautions pertaining to the instrument itself before/during/after transit would likely find a more informed audience on Music
- Bulking up to more easily lift the piano might be worth asking about on [Fitness](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/)
- You'll want to see a doctor about that hernia, but could probably get some good hernia-related information on [Health](https://health.stackexchange.com/) to read while you're recuperating.
- When your piano reaches its destination and you have to modify the house to get it inside, ask for help on [Home Improvement](https://diy.stackexchange.com/).
- If you plan this properly, your piano won't fall and you shouldn't need a titanium suit to protect you - so [stay away from Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/209284/would-a-titanium-suit-save-your-life-from-a-piano-falling-on-you).

Comment: Perfect -- my main concern is preserving marital harmony by not smashing my wife's piano during the move, so I'll try asking on Music.

Comment: @josilber I guess it's too bad that [Relationships and Dating](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/44577/relationships-and-dating) was closed.

Comment: Who needs social solutions when there are so many technical ones?