# Where to ask "how to dissassemble lk-55 piano"?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Please recomend a SE site for the following question.

I don't know if I have to be very specific with the details of my actual question here. In short:

> I have a casio "electronic keyboard" (musical instrument), model is
>   lk-55. I need to dissasemble it (because it's mine and I want to 
>   clean it/ repair it/ see the inside / make use of the parts.
>   The problem is that there is a cover and a back. I must pull apart
>   them in order to access all the mechanism inside. But there are
>   various cables, apparently solded, are they solded ? What to do? Is
>   this dissasembleable?

That's all. Maybe a technology site? I think there isn't.

Comment: Not quite a duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/267031/where-can-i-ask-questions-about-moving-a-grand-piano

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your question could probably find a home at our [Music: Practise and Theory](https://music.stackexchange.com/) site.

From their [tour](https://music.stackexchange.com/tour/):

> Ask about:
>
> - Instrument maintenance

Your question would probably fit under this heading.